# Lucene out of memory while opening file multiple time

Tags: java, indexing, lucene, out-of-memory

My application get multiple request per second we have bot's crawling our site. I use Lucene for Indexing and searching. For the 1st request when the site is restart application opens the Lucene indexed file and store it. So from second request it will look into the stored object.
But the issue is till the file is completely open and store there are multiple request which will try to open the file again. 
This causes the site to go out of memory after 5-10 minutes.

**This are the following errors.**

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
    at java.util.TreeMap.put(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.FieldInfos.<init>(FieldInfos.java:61)
    at org.apache.lucene.codecs.lucene42.Lucene42FieldInfosReader.read(Lucene42FieldInfosReader.java:96)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentCoreReaders.<init>(SegmentCoreReaders.java:121)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentReader.<init>(SegmentReader.java:56)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.StandardDirectoryReader$1.doBody(StandardDirectoryReader.java:62)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentInfos$FindSegmentsFile.run(SegmentInfos.java:783)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.StandardDirectoryReader.open(StandardDirectoryReader.java:52)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.DirectoryReader.open(DirectoryReader.java:66)
    at com.webjaguar.web.frontend.LuceneCategery.getLuceneProduct(LuceneCategery.java:166)
    at com.webjaguar.web.frontend.CategoryController.handleRequest(CategoryController.java:1034)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:48)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:624)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:312)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:324)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:324)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:324)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
```

**SECOND ERROR**

```
   Exception in thread "Lucene Merge Thread #9" org.apache.lucene.index.MergePolicy$MergeException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at org.apache.lucene.index.ConcurrentMergeScheduler.handleMergeException(ConcurrentMergeScheduler.java:541)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.ConcurrentMergeScheduler$MergeThread.run(ConcurrentMergeScheduler.java:514)
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
java.lang.IllegalStateException: this writer hit an OutOfMemoryError; cannot commit
    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.prepareCommitInternal(IndexWriter.java:2661)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.commitInternal(IndexWriter.java:2827)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.closeInternal(IndexWriter.java:981)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.close(IndexWriter.java:883)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.close(IndexWriter.java:845)
    at com.webjaguar.thirdparty.lucene.LuceneProductIndexer.reIndex(LuceneProductIndexer.java:750)
    at com.webjaguar.web.quartz.LuceneProductJob.autoIndex(LuceneProductJob.java:90)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.util.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:273)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean$MethodInvokingJob.executeInternal(MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean.java:311)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.QuartzJobBean.execute(QuartzJobBean.java:113)
    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:223)
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:549)
```

**THIS LINE IS THE ERROR LINE**

```
reader = DirectoryReader.open(NIOFSDirectory.open(indexFile));
```

Is there a way to lock the file till it is store. Any solution to improve the way it should be implemented

Comment: which version of lucene do you use? 4.2?

Comment: It might help to reuse the reader, instead of opening a new reader on every request. You can call `DirectoryReader.openIfChanged(oldReader)` to open a new reader only when necessary.

Comment: @femtoRgon Yes I am using lucene 4.2.1. I am doing the same once I have values in reader. I store it in Resource.getInstance and I re-use the same one if it has value. BUT the issue is Before storing it to the resource it is trying to open the index file again as the request are coming back to back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have a look at the `LockFactory` of the `NIOFSDirectory` (inherited from parent `Directory`).
See [LockFactory Javadoc for little more informations](https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_2_0/core/org/apache/lucene/store/LockFactory.html)

Additional to this, your requirements look like a NRT (near-real-time) use case for me. If you like to index and search within a short time period and indexing will be done continuous a NRT implementation would make sense. I'm not sure if this is already a feature of lucene v4.2.
See [Simple NRT tutorial](http://www.lucenetutorial.com/lucene-nrt-hello-world.html) for additional information.